# How to return a file directory(source tree) in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, ftp

I need to get the file directory from controller. when i do visit to one url I want to get like this.
is there any way to create with spring controller by doing a get request without FTP server.

[image]

can someone pleases give me some idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> fileTree(@RequestParam String path) {
    File file = new File(BASE_PATH + path);
    // check if file exists etc
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Arrays.stream(file.listFiles())
                                   .map(File::getName)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Something like that should work, basically you can get the files inside another file with `File#listFiles` and then do with them wathever you want.

Comment: this is just a string. i directory as a  output.

Comment: @Ragulan I just got the fileName but you could get any information that you want from the files, construct an object with the map and then return it. What’s the problem?